# How to use Java applet to get/restart the services running on a server?

Tags: java, active-directory, applet, ldap

I have a Java Applet that uses LDAP to get a list of all the servers on Active Directory. The Applet puts all of the servers into a drop down list.

The next step is to select one of these servers and then display a list of all the services running on that server. Is there a way of getting all of the services running on a server?

The final goal is to be able to restart a service from the Applet. Is this possible? And if so, what is the best approach?

Thanks

Comment: No one wants to answer or no one knows the answer? Or am I missing important details?

Comment: Sorry. I have spent a lot of time researching this but have come up empty handed. I would appritiate an answer when you get time.

Comment: *"display a list of all the services"*  Many things on servers are not intended for inspection or use by external parties (people surfing into the server from the internet).  In many cases that would be a severe security threat.  I am *not sure* if the functionality you mention is like that, but if so, the only way for the applet to invoke access that functionality is to have the server provide a public interface to it (e.g. via servlets, ASP or PHP).

Comment: To get the list of servers I am using username and password from the user. Also the applet is signed to get out of the browser's sandbox. I am able to get and restart services with vbscript so there is some sort of interface. However, the site needs to work with mozilla and chrome, not just ie. I am hoping to find a Java example that I can modify.

Comment: In that case I can provide no more useful information beyond noting that *if* an applet is 'phoning home' to its own server, it should *not* need to be trusted.  Best of luck with it.

Comment: @bigal: Your question looks quite clear (I changed the tags to [tag:active-directory] instead of [tag:directory] and [tag:active]), but I don't know anything about LDAP or ActiveDirectory, sorry. I suppose the number of people which know both applets and LDAP is not so large.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should research the feasibility of the final goal first, rather than the user interface. It isn't implementable without a service in the server that can listen to the applet and start the specified service. Compared to that, the applet side is pretty trivial. I strongly suspect what you want isn't feasible, for example in Windows where many servers are *services* that are controlled via the Control Panel->Services or the NET START command run with admin privilege.

Comment: A simple web based active directory manager is what I am aiming for. I know this is posible becuase there are some commercial products that do this. I wish I knew how they acomplish this. Perhaps these products are worth the investment.